# maven spring library correct dependency

Tags: spring

Let's say I am creating a new project, maven based, and I want to use  spring 4.2.3.RELEASE.
I also want to use spring-test and spring security and X, Y and Z.
How can I know for sure what exact versions to add in maven to avoid conflicts?
Thanks

## later edit:

can this help me?

Maven "Bill Of Materials" Dependency

It is possible to accidentally mix different versions of Spring JARs when using Maven. For example, you may find that a third-party library, or another Spring project, pulls in a transitive dependency to an older release. If you forget to explicitly declare a direct dependency yourself, all sorts of unexpected issues can arise.

To overcome such problems Maven supports the concept of a "bill of materials" (BOM) dependency. You can import the spring-framework-bom in your dependencyManagement section to ensure that all spring dependencies (both direct and transitive) are at the same version.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

An added benefit of using the BOM is that you no longer need to specify the `<version>` attribute when depending on Spring Framework artifacts:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Comment: What would be X, Y and Z? Other Spring modules?

Comment: It was a simple example. Any module. How would I know what version of some module I need (from spring suit) that will work with 4.2.3.RELEASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the BOM is one of the most powerfull ways to fight (even maven based) dependency hell.

Comment: One more question, let's say I have a dependency of org.springframework and I want so to add a dependency of spring-security. How do I know what version of spring-security I need in order to fit the org. requirements?

Comment: @DiLIVIO in this case you have to look at the reference documentation of spring security http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom or have a look at spring-securitys pom to find out which version they used (Eclipse Pom Editor, Tab Dependency-Hierarchy helps a lot)